# Accordion - Scroll Content within DIV

Tags: php, html, css, scroll

I'm using the accordion code from:

www.mraffaele.com/labs/css-only-accordions/

This works well but I'd like to vertically scroll content on one tile.

This [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/9tpwx6xh/) shows what I've currently got working.
TITLE TWO Scrolls the div contents. but I'm trying to make it only scroll a specific part of the tile. This [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/9tpwx6xh/2/) shows what I'm trying to scroll.

Currently I'm doing this by adding 
`overflow:auto;`

to

```
.horizontal [type=radio]:checked ~ label ~ .content
```

I thought about putting the text and form fields I want to scroll in a new DIV and set the     `overflow:auto;` against that, but it didn't seem to work.

Any idea how I can do this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
/*
*
*    Author:    Michael Raffaele <michael@mraffaele.com>
*    Date:    25th October 2011
*    Info:     http://www.mraffaele.com/blog/2011/10/25/css-accordion-no-javascript/
*
*/

/* Shared for all accordion types */
.accordion {
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
    margin:0 auto;
    font-size:14px;
    border:1px solid #542437;
    border-radius:10px;
    width:600px;
    padding:10px;
    background:#fff;
}
.accordion ul {
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;    
}
.accordion li {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.accordion [type=radio], .accordion [type=checkbox] {
    display:none;
}
.accordion label {
    display:block;
    font-size:16px;
    line-height:16px;
    background:#D95B43;
    border:1px solid #542437;
    color:#542437;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
    font-weight:700;
    cursor:pointer;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all .2s ease-out;
}
.accordion ul li label:hover, .accordion [type=radio]:checked ~ label, .accordion [type=checkbox]:checked ~ label {
    background:#C02942;
    color:#FFF;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5)
}
.accordion .content {
    padding:0 10px;
    overflow:hidden;
    border:1px solid #fff; /* Make the border match the background so it fades in nicely */
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease-out;
}
.accordion p {
    color:#333;
    margin:0 0 10px;
}
.accordion h3 {
    color:#542437;
    padding:0;
    margin:10px 0;
}

/* Horizontal */
/* Unfortunately fixed heights need to be set for this */
.horizontal {
    overflow:hidden;
    height:300px;
}
.horizontal ul li {
    float:left;
    margin:0 1px 0 0;
}
.horizontal ul li label {
    word-wrap:break-word;
    letter-spacing:10px;
    text-align:center;
    height:280px;
    padding:10px 0 10px 5px;
    width:25px;
    float:left;
}
.horizontal ul li .content {
    height:300px;
    padding:0;
    display:inline-block; /* Makes its work in FF */
    visibility:hidden; /* Chrome bug cant show width < 1px for some reason so need to toggle visibility */
    width:1px;
    border-left:0;
    overflow:auto;
}
.horizontal [type=radio]:checked ~ label {
    border-right:0;    
}
.horizontal ul li label:hover {
    border:1px solid #542437; /* Again, we don't want the border to disappear on hover */
}
.horizontal [type=radio]:checked ~ label ~ .content {    
    visibility:visible;
    width:442px;
    padding:0 10px;
    border:1px solid #542437;
    border-left:0;    
}
```

```html
<div class="accordion horizontal">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <input type="radio" id="vert-1" name="vert-accordion" checked="checked" />
            <label for="vert-1">Title&nbsp;One</label>
            <div class="content">
                <h3>This is an example accordion item</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse nec posuere lorem. Pellentesque hendrerit, lorem luctus porttitor vestibulum, eros sapien mattis libero, euismod congue neque nisi at ipsum. Mauris semper ipsum sit amet metus semper malesuada. Donec vel est justo, ac porta diam.</p>
                <p>In ut est in orci commodo blandit. Cras rhoncus ultricies augue. Proin quam odio, venenatis ut tempus tristique, aliquet in velit. Pellentesque volutpat facilisis orci, ut congue mi rhoncus at. Nullam vehicula dignissim neque, sed rhoncus magna ultricies et.</p>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="radio" id="vert-2" name="vert-accordion" />
            <label for="vert-2">Title&nbsp;Two</label>
            <div class="content">
                <h3>Totally another one right here</h3>
                <p>This should be static text and images that don't scroll. This should be static text and images that don't scroll. This should be static text and images that don't scroll. This should be static text and images that don't scroll.</p>
                
<h2> Only scroll from this point </h2>                
                <div style="overflow: auto;height: 120px;">
                <p>In ut est in orci commodo blandit. Cras rhoncus ultricies augue. Proin quam odio, venenatis ut tempus tristique, aliquet in velit. Pellentesque volutpat facilisis orci, ut congue mi rhoncus at. Nullam vehicula dignissim neque, sed rhoncus magna ultricies et.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse nec posuere lorem. Pellentesque hendrerit, lorem luctus porttitor vestibulum, eros sapien mattis libero, euismod congue neque nisi at ipsum. Mauris semper ipsum sit amet metus semper malesuada. Donec vel est justo, ac porta diam.</p>
                <p>In ut est in orci commodo blandit. Cras rhoncus ultricies augue. Proin quam odio, venenatis ut tempus tristique, aliquet in velit. Pellentesque volutpat facilisis orci, ut congue mi rhoncus at. Nullam vehicula dignissim neque, sed rhoncus magna ultricies et.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse nec posuere lorem. Pellentesque hendrerit, lorem luctus porttitor vestibulum, eros sapien mattis libero, euismod congue neque nisi at ipsum. Mauris semper ipsum sit amet metus semper malesuada. Donec vel est justo, ac porta diam.</p>
                <p>In ut est in orci commodo blandit. Cras rhoncus ultricies augue. Proin quam odio, venenatis ut tempus tristique, aliquet in velit. Pellentesque volutpat facilisis orci, ut congue mi rhoncus at. Nullam vehicula dignissim neque, sed rhoncus magna ultricies et.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse nec posuere lorem. Pellentesque hendrerit, lorem luctus porttitor vestibulum, eros sapien mattis libero, euismod congue neque nisi at ipsum. Mauris semper ipsum sit amet metus semper malesuada. Donec vel est justo, ac porta diam.</p>
                <p>In ut est in orci commodo blandit. Cras rhoncus ultricies augue. Proin quam odio, venenatis ut tempus tristique, aliquet in velit. Pellentesque volutpat facilisis orci, ut congue mi rhoncus at. Nullam vehicula dignissim neque, sed rhoncus magna ultricies et.</p>
                </div>


            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="radio" id="vert-3" name="vert-accordion" />
            <label for="vert-3">Title&nbsp;Three</label>
            <div class="content">
                <h3>I think I can go on forever</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse nec posuere lorem. Pellentesque hendrerit, lorem luctus porttitor vestibulum, eros sapien mattis libero, euismod congue neque nisi at ipsum. Mauris semper ipsum sit amet metus semper malesuada. Donec vel est justo, ac porta diam.</p>
                <p>In ut est in orci commodo blandit. Cras rhoncus ultricies augue. Proin quam odio, venenatis ut tempus tristique, aliquet in velit. Pellentesque volutpat facilisis orci, ut congue mi rhoncus at. Nullam vehicula dignissim neque, sed rhoncus magna ultricies et.</p>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="radio" id="vert-4" name="vert-accordion" />
            <label for="vert-4">Title&nbsp;Four</label>
            <div class="content">
                <h3>I was wrong, I'm done</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse nec posuere lorem. Pellentesque hendrerit, lorem luctus porttitor vestibulum, eros sapien mattis libero, euismod congue neque nisi at ipsum. Mauris semper ipsum sit amet metus semper malesuada. Donec vel est justo, ac porta diam.</p>
                <p>In ut est in orci commodo blandit. Cras rhoncus ultricies augue. Proin quam odio, venenatis ut tempus tristique, aliquet in velit. Pellentesque volutpat facilisis orci, ut congue mi rhoncus at. Nullam vehicula dignissim neque, sed rhoncus magna ultricies et.</p>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```